# Commutation for constraints

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Suppose from the Hamiltonian I got the [Primary constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) $$(\Phi_m,\Phi)$$ And $\dot \Phi_m$ , $\dot \Phi$ leads to secondary constraints $$(\gamma_m,\gamma)$$ respectively. Now if the commutation of $\Phi_m$ with $\gamma_m$ is non zero (i.e they both are [second class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint#Second_class_constraints)) does it terminate the commutation chain there?

Comment: Can you please explain your notation $(\Phi_m,\Phi)$ ?

Comment: $(\Phi_m,\Phi)$ are like the momenta.For Lagrangian L, $\Phi_m=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$. Same goes for $\Phi$

Comment: Then i think notation $(\Phi_1,\Phi_2)$ would be more appropriate. $m$ may be confused for a variable subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP wrote(v1):

> Now if the (Poisson) commutation of $\Phi_m$ with $\gamma_m$ is non zero (i.e they both are second class) does it terminate the (Poisson) commutation chain there?

No, not necessarily. The rest of the $4\times 4$ matrix $\{\chi^i,\chi^j\}$ of the $4$ constraints still contains unspecified entries.

Finally, don't forget to check if there are tertiary constraints, quaternary constraints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To follow the process of deducation, \dot{\kappa}={\kappa,H_T}, to find whether there are some other new constraints. If there are no any new constraints, you can be taken as you are at the end.